Проблема с selenium. Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение
У меня есть скрипт, работающий на selenium
Он выполняет действия из тг бота через эмуляцию. Работает около 16 часов, а после начинает выдавать ошибку при каждом запросе из бота к selenium:
HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=61247): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/d796fded13a66c88e38bbad6365b626f/refresh (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000023F7CC79760>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение'))
Сервер на винде. Все остальные функции бота работают исправно. Прошу помочь с проблемов
